# How to assign equity analyst recommendations to a common, numeric scale?

Tags: equities, yahoo

Yahoo finance conveniently provides [historic ratings](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ud?s=MSFT) from a number of analysts.  Unfortunately, each analyst seems to use a different scale: buy/hold/sell, perform/outperform/neutral, overweight/equal weight/underweight, etc.

I've already [written a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531238/pulling-historic-analyst-opinions-from-yahoo-finance-in-r) to scrape this data into R, and I would like to expand it by automatically coding the ratings.  I was thinking of using a -1,0,1 system, which would basically encode bad/neutral/good, and trying to shoehorn each analyst's system onto this scale.

I'm sure other people have solutions to this problem, and I'm interested to see what they are before I start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually known as equity analyst recommendations, and although the terms differ, virtually all of them grade on a 5-point scale.  Much academic research has been done using analyst recommendations, typically using the [I/B/E/S](http://thomsonreuters.com/products_services/financial/financial_products/a-z/ibes/) database (see, e.g. [Sorescu and Subrahmanyam (2006)](http://subra.x10hosting.com/ss.pdf)).

> IBES distinguishes five categories of recommendations, labeled 1 through 5, which we interpret as “strong buy,” “buy,” “hold,” “sell,” and “strong sell,” respectively.

Comment: Where do recommendations like "Sector Perform" and  "Sector Underperform" fit on this 5 point scale?

Comment: Look at this link: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ud?s=MSFT date 11-Feb-08

Comment: Go to finance.yahoo.com and search for MSFT. In the left bar, click on "Analyst Opinion," and then click on "More Upgrades and Downgrades"

Comment: @Zach Yuck! What an ugly way to present such simple data.  Still, it is clear from that page that it is on a 5-point scale.  To figure out what the 5 points are, you will need to collect a lot of data and track upgrades/downgrades and the from/to categories for each bank separately.  Perhaps someone else here knows of a definitive translation list for all the banks, but sorry, I don't.

Comment: @TalFishman IBES normalizes this data from all banks into a normalized scale. This is the only source that I have worked with for upgrades/downgrades that provides both breadth and sanity.